# Select rows from Data Frame based on listed values in R Programming

Tags: r, data-visualization, data-analysis

I am doing Exploratory Data Analytics of Sports Data using R Programming...
I want to print the records from the Data Frame based on two condition
condition :  Country == "England" ||(OR operator) Ground == ground can be any one from the below list

```
List = c("Birmingham" ,"Bristol" ,"Cardiff" ,"Chester-le-Street" , 
              "Leeds" ,"East London" ,"Lord's", "The Oval",
              "Manchester" ,"Nottingham" ,"Southampton" ,"Taunton")
```

**Sample Data (abbreviated given image provided)**

```r
data.frame(
  Ground = c('Hambantota', 'Benoni', 'Benoni', 'Hambantota', 'Hambantota',
             'Pallekele', 'Pallekele'),
  Country = c('Bangladesh', 'SouthAfrica', 'Pakistan', 'SriLanka', 'Bangladesh',
              'SriLanka', 'Bangladesh')
)
```

[image: Data Frame]

**I am trying...**

```
subset(WC_Grounds,WC_Grounds$Country=="England"||WC_Grounds %in% WC_Grounds_List)
```

but it returns the 0 records

Comment: Thank you for comment but I posted what i am doing below the image but it is not working. I am Trying using  subset(WC_Grounds,WC_Grounds$Country=="England"||WC_Grounds %in% WC_Grounds_List) only if you know how to do it using head() or dput() please answer

Comment: I want new Data Frame Which include only country as England OR grounds %in% list

Comment: We are not your clients. We don't work for you. It is your responsibility as a question asker is to make it easier for us users who are taking our own time to voluntarily help you. That said, please actually read the links I provided and edit your question to include a reproducible example.

Comment: By you posting an image of your data, you are forcing us to manually reproduce your data on our end. Please delete the image and replace it with a reproducible example. You can learn exactly how to do that by clicking and reading the reproducible example link in my first comment.

Comment: You have since marked my solution as accepted. Does it now work for you?

Comment: yes, it works for me thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

`subset(WC_Grounds, WC_Grounds$Country=="England" | WC_Grounds$Ground %in% WC_Grounds_List)`

Work for you?

> || and && - These operators are “short-circuiting”: as soon as || sees the first TRUE it returns TRUE without computing anything else. You should instead use `|` which is vectorized thus applying to the multiple values in your dataset.

Here is an example using the abbreviated sample data I added to your question:

```r
WC_Grounds <- data.frame(
  Ground = c('Hambantota', 'Benoni', 'Benoni', 'Hambantota', 'Hambantota',
             'Pallekele', 'Pallekele'),
  Country = c('Bangladesh', 'SouthAfrica', 'Pakistan', 'SriLanka', 'Bangladesh',
              'SriLanka', 'Bangladesh')
)

List = c('Hambantota', 'Benoni')

subset(WC_Grounds, WC_Grounds$Country == "SriLanka" | WC_Grounds$Ground %in% List)

#>       Ground     Country
#> 1 Hambantota  Bangladesh
#> 2     Benoni SouthAfrica
#> 3     Benoni    Pakistan
#> 4 Hambantota    SriLanka
#> 5 Hambantota  Bangladesh
#> 6  Pallekele    SriLanka
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>